# Should I use a pool of objects, a singleton or static methods in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a helper class that creates some objects, like a builder. The helper class does not have a state. It is on a multi-threaded environment; specifically, a web server. Is this class a good candidate for being a singleton?

What would be the difference between implementing this class as a singleton and just using `static` methods?

What would the effect of thousands of users accessing this object/these methods be?

I could make the class a regular class, but instantiating it every time it is needed would be a waste of memory.

Comment: "but it is a waste of memory" - how do you know this? have you tested it and seen the performance? Object allocation and the use of short-lived objects is not as expensive as you think. You are likely overthinking one teeny tiny part of your overall application.

Comment: you might be right...i was always afraid of creating not necessary objects coming from j2me environment ! each object created was analyzed carefully there...

Comment: Quick clarification; what you have sounds more like a `Factory` than a `Builder`, a `Builder` usually implies state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use singleton here (since you do not need a state), you can use static methods. 
Singleton in principle offers more control by allowing a state. There won't be much difference in your case, but static methods will be easier to implement and use.

- What would the effect of thousands of users accessing this object/these methods be?
  Again, not much difference in both cases, but in Singleton you can have a state, and if you do not implement carefully, your code will be non-thread-safe. Every user calling the static method gets its own "instance" of the method (I think this is what you ask), so no risk of running into thread-safety problems there.

Comment: -1: `static` methods can have a state. And when it comes to thread-safety `static` methods are no better than instance methods since `static` fields are just as bad as instance fields (variables located on the "stack", local, are never a problem as they are not shared).

Comment: @dacwe - I'm not aware of any java method that retains its own state.  Granted, `static` can be as bad as instance methods in accessing or modifying state - but that's a problem for the input parameters (putting `synchronized` on a static method doesn't help input parameters any).  And yes, `static` fields are equivalent (or worse) to instance variables - but this only effects static methods if they use those fields

Comment: X-Zero: You are correct, wrote to quickly, I ment saying that *"`static` methods can modify `static` fields like a singleton object method modifies the objects variables"* - it's no different.

Answer (score 2):

Infact instead of singleton you can make the methods `static`.

Singleton doesn't have to be only 1, you can create a pool of instances and delegate work depending on the requirement, where as you don't have such control with static methods.

discussion on `Singleton vs Static methods` is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)

Comment: Please tell me what is a `static` stand-alone class?

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. My -1 vote removed (though someone else gave you one -- and this shouldn't be done without a comment -- and now it's removed. Go figure).

Comment: Isn't the definition of a singleton that it can to be only one?

Comment: @dacwe: yes but,... I'm no expert on singletons, but I think that there can be more than one singleton object if more than one class loader is used. Experts, please correct any errors in my statements! **Edit:** as Manoj's link discusses. 1+

Comment: @Hovercraft: No, a definition is a definition. If you have more than one it is no longer a singleton - no matter how you do. Why not just have the pool of instances *inside* the singleton?

Comment: @dacwe: are you saying that even if a program uses more than one class loader, there can only be one singleton instance in the program?

Comment: @Hovercraft: Yes, if the classes are loaded by two different classloaders they are treated as distinct classes by the JVM. `classLoadedFromOneClassLoader.equals(classLoadedFromAnotherClassLoader)` will return `false`. However (I don't want to go down this route, but you leave me no choice :)) you can surely break the "singletoness" by changing the underlying instance using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, singletons are used to have only one instance of the object present at the time. So singleton does have a state, but you're accessing to that one state wherever you're calling your singleton.

So if you don't need any state saved in your class/method I'd suggest to use static approach.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated before, given that your class doesn't have object state, static methods would work just fine.
However, consider the following - Depending on the overall design of your system, you may want to be able to specify a different implementation of the methods.  This is usually done with either subclassing (...), or interface implementation (now the preferred method) - look up the strategy pattern.  In either case, being able to provide alternte implementations would require you to *not* use static methods, but to have an (empty) object to call methods on.